# Can't unignore files in Team Explorer Everywhere in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs, tfvc, team-explorer-everywhere

I am using TFVC.

I have two files which show the `[Ignored]` tag in project explorer. Right clicking on them, `unignore` is greyed out.

The files are .jasper files from the Jasper reporting framework, located in `/src/main/resources` in one of my modules. No other files in that folder have this problem.

I do have a .tfignore file, but it doesn't have anything that would match these files:

```
target
.settings
.project
.classpath
\<redacted module name>\application.properties
\<redacted module name>\.springBeans
\<redacted module name>\app
\<redacted module name>\tree
\tree
```

It's only for my environment -- my teammates aren't seeing it, so I know it's not a TFS server config issue.

Answer (score 0):

First in your mapped folder at local computer, double check your local `.tfignore` file.  And since the effects of the `.tfignore` file are recursive. Check if there are any `.tfignore` files in sub-folders to override the effects of a `.tfignore` file in a parent folder.

And you could also try to explicitly declare do no ignore the files in the  `.tfignore`, then save it and restart the eclipse.

```
# Do not ignore .jasper files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.jasper
```

Another possibility is related to cache issue, try to clear the cache info(check in or back up  the local changes first) in team explorer everywhere.

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\\Microsoft\Team Explorer
```

More detail about the cache info please refer this [thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413269(v=vs.100).aspx#Cannot%20find%20the%20cache%20or%20settings%20files).